# How can i get code to work for RWD image map on ipad and mobile website?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a banner for the top of one of the pages and added a logo at `http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/test/im-new-here.html`the upper left hand corner of the banner.  I would like to use the logo as a link to the main page.  I set it up as a circle because it just a bigger target for click (especially on mobile site and ipad).  I cannot get it to work on ipad or mobile site.  I am new to this and need some help.  I opted for this method because I thought the imaged resized nicer as part of the banner image.  The url is http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/test/im-new-here.html.

```
<style>
    img[usemap] {
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

</style>

<div id="bg-container">
     <img src="images/test-bg2.png" usemap="#logomap">
          <map name="logomap">
              <area shape="circle" coords="200,90,175"
                    href="index.html" alt="main page">
          </map>
</div>

<!-- this is for side bar menu-->
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">              </script><style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-    ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/simpleslider/jquery.simplesidebar.min.js"></script>

<!-- image map stuff-->
<script src="jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>


 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();

    $('area').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('alt') + ' clicked');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "top-bar" div (which is transparent) is on top of the upper part of the image, covering the clickable area.

Try adding this to your CSS (inside the  tags):

```
div#top-bar {
  height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
#header a{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

to make the link the size of its content.